# Custom bibliography and footcite styles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I use the following packages with the document class `article`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle,bibstyle=numeric,url=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
```

I have very strict rules for my project thesis, especially about the bibliography and footnotes. I read I can adapt the `.bbx` files to achieve custom styles, however, I don't understand those.

These are my requirements:

- **Bibliography (sorted by last name)**:

  - Books: Last, First. Year. Title. Subtitle (edition). Publisher.
  - Online: Last, First. Year/Date. Title. Subtitle. Accessed on Date at URL.
  - Incollection: Last, First. Year. Title. Subtitle. In Editor (some static text here), Booktitle (S. Page numbers). Publisher.
- **Footnotes (and `\cite` in footnotes?)**:

  - First reference to book on page: Last name, Year, Title(, S. Page)
  - Additional references to the same item on the same page: Last, Year(, S. Page)

**A numbered bibliography is not required.**

How could I achieve this? The `numeric` bibstyle comes close to what I want, except from details such as the order of information and the separating dots.

**Update**: Here is a MWE (not too small to cover all requirements):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle,bibstyle=numeric,url=true,isbn=false,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}

% ===============================
% JUST AN EXAMPLE BIBLIOGRAPHY DB
% ===============================
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book2009,
  author = "John Doe",
  title = "A friendly word to the world",
  subtitle = "A book with a subtitle",
  year = 2009,
  publisher = "Great Publisher"
}
@book{book2011,
  author = "Jane Foo",
  title = "A great book with a terrible title",
  % No subtitle
  year = 2011,
  publisher = "Awesome Inc."
}
@online{online2012,
  author = "Bar Baz",
  title = "Hang on, I'll get you",
  % No subtitle
  year = 2012,
  url = "http://example.com",
  urldate = "2014-04-21"
}
@online{online2014,
  author = "Michael Smith",
  title = "Wait for Smith",
  subtitle = "It's okay",
  year = 2014,
  url = "http://foo.example.com",
  urldate = "2014-04-21"
}
\end{filecontents}
% ===============================

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
% TOC etc.

% CONTENTS
\section{First chapter}

It\footcite[38]{book2009} was\footcite{online2014} a\footcite[234]{book2009} sunny\footcite{online2012} day\footcite{book2009} when I noticed\footcite{book2011} it.

% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\clearpage
\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

% LOF etc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your requirements. (What about `@article`s, `@inbook`s etc. Is there any stile guide you could point us to?) Are you sure you want `numeric` and not `authoryear`? Especially seeing that you now have `citestyle=authortitle,bibstyle=numeric` in your MWE, which is almost certainly a bad idea. Also your MWE is not really helpful: It does not compile (there is not `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`) and contains a lot of packages unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: @moewe I added some more information and removed unrelated packages. I am currently writing a MWE.

Comment: @moewe I added a MWE.

Comment: I tried to find a solution, but I can't get `\ifsamepage` with `authoryear-ibid` to work, and I don't know why.

Comment: Are you formatting all citations in footnotes or are you using inline citations at all. (Weird that the style even suggests a mixture.) Do you really want the bibliography items numbered? That makes no sense and is not mentioned in the style guidelines you posted. Are other types of entry excluded because you are not using them at all? And why are you trying to use `authoryear-ibid` when the style guidelines explicitly say to do something different?

Comment: `authoryear-ibid` comes from me, because the questioner wants `Additional references to the same item on the same page: Last, Year(, S. Page)`. With any `-ibid`-style you *should* be able to use `\ifsamepage`. But doesn't work for me.

Comment: @cfr You are right, a numbered bibliography is not required. I was told to use footnotes and thought I could use some inline citations as well, but I asked about it and it turns out that I must not use anything except from footnotes. Sorry for that, will edit question. Do you have any suggestions how I could solve this? I am quite inexperienced with biblatex.

Comment: This looks *very* close to chicago-notes, which is part of `biblatex-chicago` except for the position of the year in the bibliography (which is odd: it's the usual position in author/year styles, but not in notes styles). I'd strongly suggest you have a look at that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: I actually came close enough with a custom variant of *authoryear*. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since the OP seems to have resolved the question (which came close to a "please write the bibstyle for me" question), I vote to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a particular change in `biblatex`, but about a whole bunch of modifications that can be found on this site already. Furthermore, the OP seems to have resolved the question themselves (see comment above).